# Is this an acceptable method to send SOAP API envelope using PHP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, php

I'm trying to post a SOAP envelope to the ExactTarget API using this PHP:

**http_post_data('https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx',$xml);**

(where variable $xml is the SOAP envelope)

**I'm seeing is error:**

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 12 Jun 2014 14:54:33 GMT
Connection: close

The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

Comment: Please post your envelope so we can have a look.

Comment: Thank Timothy, you can find my soap here: http://www.rbiforms.co.uk/PHIL/soap.txt